# How to pass implemented listener to AsyncTask via constructor?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

**Interface:**

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted{
    void onTaskCompleted(Document doc);
}
```

Extended `Activity` with this `Interface`:

```
public Activity implements OnTaskCompleted{
   //Activity
}
```

Let the `AsyncTask` send an information when it's done.

```
public MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Object,Object>{ 
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;

    // all your stuff
    public MyAsyncTask(OnTaskCompleted listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object o){
        listener.onTaskCompleted(doc);
    }
}
```

But how do I pass this to when I instantiate the listener?

```
public Activity implements OnTaskCompleted{
    //Activity
    @Override
    onTaskCompleted(Object o){
        //Do something in activity
    }
    ...onCreate... {
        asyncTask = new YourTask(???????);
        asyncTask.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `this` to the constructor:

```
asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);
```

Your Activity implements `OnTaskCompleted`, so it's eligible to pass to `MyAsyncTask`

Comment: So basically because I implemented OnTaskCompleted to my Activity, `this`is now of type `OnTaskCompleted`?